# graph api post action on facebook from facebook c# sdk

Tags: facebook, graph

I am trying to make an action to be posted on facebook but I am getting an error " OAuthException) Error validating application. Invalid application ID "

here is my code :

```
    var fb = new FacebookClient("TesterAccessToken");

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.dyno_run = "http://samples.ogp.me/3153962321975196100";
        parameters.appnamespace = "NameSpace";
        parameters.action = "comment";
        parameters.object_name = "nice_image";
        parameters.object_url = "MyURL";

        try
        {
            dynamic result = fb.Post("me/", parameters);
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException ex)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting on wall using below code on friend's wall

```
 Facebook.Web.FacebookWebClient client = new Facebook.Web.FacebookWebClient(accesstoken);                
            dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
            parameters.message = "";
            parameters.link = link;
            parameters.name = name;
            parameters.caption = caption;
            parameters.description = desc;
            parameters.from = fromId;    
            object resTest = client.Post("/" + friendId + "/feed", parameters);
```

You can post on your wall by using

```
  object resTest = client.Post("/me/feed", parameters);
```

Comment: I am trying to post from the application as an action post , posting a regular status i think will be working normally . I tried creating the facebook client as app id and app secret , and adding access_token as parameter (parameters.access_token) , but am still facing the same error.

Comment: As an action post, you can use FB Graph API, i was having issues in posting actions but now i've done successfully check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

Comment: I am using c# and facebook c# sdk , do you have a code sample on that? using code similiar like the one i am posting and as urs.

Comment: I had used C# sdk but its now old so its better to use Graph API also publishing action is new feature so may be it'll not available in C# sdk